# Make google drive api multi threading

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Im trying to build a new wrapper to make my google drive api client thread safe and multi threading.
So I have this code, 2 files:

APIConnector.py:

```
import logging
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any, Callable, List, Optional

import google.auth
import httplib2
from google_auth_httplib2 import AuthorizedHttp
from googleapiclient.http import HttpRequest
import APIConnector


@dataclass
class APIConnector:
    factory: Callable[[], AuthorizedHttp]
    pool: List[AuthorizedHttp] = field(default_factory=[])

    @classmethod
    def new(
            cls,
            credentials: google.auth.Credentials,
            initial_size: int = 5,
            timeout_seconds: int = 10,
    ) -> APIConnector:
        factory = lambda: AuthorizedHttp(
            credentials,
            http=httplib2.Http(timeout=timeout_seconds)
        )
        pool: List[AuthorizedHttp] = []
        for i in range(initial_size):
            pool.append(factory())

        return cls(factory, pool=pool)

    def execute(self, req: HttpRequest) -> Any:
        http: Optional[AuthorizedHttp] = None
        try:
            http = self._provision_http()
            return req.execute(http=http)
        finally:
            if http:
                self.pool.append(http)

    def _provision_http(self) -> AuthorizedHttp:
        # This function can run in parallel in multiple threads.
        try:
            return self.pool.pop()
        except IndexError:
            logging.info("Pool exhausted. Creating new transport")
            return self.factory()
```

and GSuiteUserManager.py

```
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass

import googleapiclient
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth.credentials import Credentials

import GSuiteUserManager
from ngus_crawlers.googledrive.APIConnector import APIConnector


@dataclass
class GSuiteUserManager:
    api: APIConnector
    users: googleapiclient.discovery.Resource
    domain: str

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, domain, credentials) -> GSuiteUserManager:
        api = APIConnector.new(Credentials)
        service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            "admin",
            "directory_v1",
            credentials=credentials,
            cache_discovery=False,
        )
        users = service.users()
        return cls(api=api, users=users, domain=domain)

    def list(self) -> dict:
        return self.api.execute(
            self.users.list(domain=self.domain)
        )

    def get(self, email: str) -> dict:
        pass
```

my question is so,
how do I make this function to use the new code:

```
def connect_logic(config: dict[str]) -> googleapiclient.discovery.Resource:
    logging.info("Connecting to google drive...")
    credentials: Credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(
        info=config[GD_CONFIG][TOKEN_CONFIG], scopes=config[GD_CONFIG][SCOPES])
    service: googleapiclient.discovery.Resource = build("drive", "v3", credentials=credentials)
    logging.info("Successfully logged into google drive")
    return service
```

or even, how do I make line like this to use the new code:

```
 raw_data = service.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields='*').execute()
```

Huge thanks to everyone who helps!